# Obj-C, trying to set accessability (including label) for the UIDatePicker?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ui-automation

I haven't got a clue where to start and how far I can go.

I would like to add labels for individual values in the the date picker.

But I'm not sure if this is possible and how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I haven't got a clue where to start

Always start with the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html).